# Chebyshev Inequality-Dice Rolling

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions

I have a problem at probability.I solved the problem, but I don't know if it's correct how I did it. A colleague of mine solved it too and got another result. I have attached my solution below.

The problem: How many times do we have to roll a dice so that, with a probability of 0.9, face 3 appears with a frequency between 1/6-0.1 and 1/6+0.1.(use Chebyshev inequality)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While your solution correctly tells you that $\ m=139\ $ is *sufficient* to achieve the desired  probability bound, and consequently that the *smallest* value of $\ m\ $ *necessary* to achieve the bound is no larger than that, it nevertheless gives a *very poor* approximation to the *true* smallest such value of $\ m\ $.

The *precise* smallest value of $\ m\ $ necessary to achieve the bound is in fact only $30$ (if the frequency $\ f\ $ is only required to satisfy $\ \frac{1}{15}\le f\le\frac{4}{15}\ $) or $38$ (if it's required to satisfy the strict inequalities $\ \frac{1}{15}< f<\frac{4}{15}\ $).

**P.S.** I should note, however, that $\ P\left(\left|X-\frac{1}{6}\right|\le0.1 \right)<$$0.9\ $ for $\ 31\le m\le37\ $, even though $\ P\left(\left|X-\frac{1}{6}\right|\le0.1 \right)\approx$$0.92>$$0.9\ $ for $\ m=30\ $.